# Order objects in hierarchic lists acording to their mutual dependence

Tags: algorithm

I've some objects with mutual dependencies.

- A
- B (depend of A)
- C (depend of B)
- D
- E (depend of B and F)
- F (depend of C)
- G
- H (depend of B)

I want to create hierarchic list of these objects where an object is placed in a list who are after the list containing it's dependences.

The previou object list will be placed like this:

1. A, D, G (these objects have no dependencies)
2. B       (B depend of A)
3. C, H    (C and H depends of B)
4. F       (F depend of C)
5. E       (E depend of B and F)

Wich algorithm can resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't any helping structure already, then you should use brute force.

I would use a list, which would extend vertically in the schema and one for every node of the vertical list.

So, in your example, I would have 5 nodes in the vertical list and for the first node, I would have a list with 3 nodes (the first node will host A, the second D and the third G). The second node of the vertical list, will have a list with one node, which will hold B and so on.

So the algorithm would be something like this:

```
1.For every item
2.  if item.dependency in list
3.    append item in the correct node
4.  else // item not in list
5.    create node in list with the dependency of the item
6.    append item in the created node
```

So, in the above pseudo-code, when I say list, I mean the vertical one.

At step 1, we check all the items you have.

At step 2, you check if the item you are currently processing exists in the list (by searching the entire list and returning the position found or something smarter).

At step 3, you go at the position found in step 2 and you insert at the end of list located at the node in position the value of your item (you don't need to store the dependency again). Note that if the node in position has no entries in it's list, then you need to also create it's list.

At step 4, we are in the case that our item is not found in the list.

At step 5, we create a new node in the list, which will have as value the dependency of the item .

At step 6, we insert the item in the node created at step 5.

Hope this helps!